# When describing a logo to an artist you've hired, what should you write and in what format?

Tags: technical-writing

When describing a logo to an artist you've hired, what should you write and in what format? Tried to find some documents intended for artists, so that I can have an artist reproduce my design from written form to actual graphics, but I am not sure what to include and in what format. I am trying to do it as professionally as possible, so I would need to see some examples to learn from them.

Comment: If you already hired an artist, talk to them. If they're professionals at creating logos, then they should know how to pull all the information they need from you. That's _their_ job.

Comment: It depends a lot, e.g. whether you have a rough idea what you want it to look like, or just want to say "Make me a logo that looks futuristic and has birds in it, and make it blue." Designers tend to be visually-minded, so consider using a sketch, or find existing pictures you can refer to, even if it's only for a small detail ("I want a font like this, and the bit at the bottom like in this picture..."). Even if you're terrible at art, don't be embarrassed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create something called "Creative brief". There is no one format that covers all situations, it is not the same if you are writing a brief for a small company or some big corp.

Take a look at some general guidelines:

- https://logosbynick.com/sample-creative-brief-for-logo-design/
- https://kaizenbrandevolution.com/how-to-write-a-perfect-logo-design-brief/
- https://www.twine.net/blog/example-logo-project-brief/
- https://99designs.com/blog/tips/logo-design-brief/

In a nutshell, you should let the designer know the basic company info, tagline, colors, target audience, a sentiment that you want to achieve, etc.

It would be best to reserve some time to discuss each point with the designer. If they have been in a game for a long time, they know what should be avoided.